# prepend random images to div

Tags: jquery, image

I have 3 divs containing different images, when a user clicks on one of the divs I want to put a new image in the divs. I know using prepend could work but I don't know how to "target" random images. I made a small jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/59bb8/2/

```
$(".art").click(function(){
  $(".art").prepend('img src');
});
```

Comment: which image do you want to prepend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare a `var` or `clone` an existent `image`

```
var img = "<img src='path/to/newimage' alt='' />"; //if you know the path
//var img = $(".art").eq(-1).find('img').clone();  if they are all equal just select the last one

$(".art").click(function(){
  $(this).prepend(img); //on current div
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59bb8/4/

edited jsfiddle with `clone` function.

If you want to prepend to all `.art` `div`, you have to use `siblings()` `method`

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at the Edited Code of your JS fiddle  on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/59bb8/5/)

```
Here it works.
```

Comment: Although this works, it does not randomize the output.